# How can I make one <DIV> visible below a second <DIV> when I hover over the second <DIV>

Tags: html, css

In my code I have a main `<div>` and a smaller one. When I hover the main `<div>` it goes down and the smaller one shows up. But then the mouse ends up over the small `<div>`, and the main `<div>` comes back up.

Here a graphical representation:

```
---------
|        |
|   main |
|   div  |
----------
```

After when hovering over the main `<div>`:

```
 -----
|  sub|
|  div|
 -----

-----------
|   main |
|   div  |
|        |
----------
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
   <style>

     #Target
      {
        background-color: red;
         opacity:.1;
     margin:20px;
     padding:0;
     float:left;
     z-index:1;
     position:absolute;
       }
     #Hovered
      {
    background-color:#0F0;
    z-index:0;
    float:left;
          width:330;
        opacity:1;
        height:200px;
         background-image:url(phpcenter/logo.PNG);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        transition:all 1s;  
        z-index:2;
        width:330px;
        opacity:.1;
       }
    #Hovered:hover
    {
        background-position:0 500%; 
    }

    #Target:hover, #Hovered:hover + #Target
       {
        opacity:1;
     transition:1s;
       }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="Hovered">Hover me</div>
    <div id="Target"><a href="#">about me</a><br><a href="#">resume</a></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I only read is ***go down*** in your question, nothing else

Comment: I was pretty confused reading this question. Thought it was just because it was early in the morning.

Comment: Why don't you supply a jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/brightpixel/PW4cW/

Comment: Riddles every where....

Comment: LOL .. but.. whats the query here?

Comment: Did you tried display style attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so css3 has siblings selector `~`, which can help to do this.

**Try this:**

```
#Hovered{background-color:#0F0; height:80px; width:330px; width:330px; z-index:0;}
#Target{background-color:red; margin:20px; opacity:.1; padding:0; transition:all 1s; position:absolute; top:15px; width:290px; z-index:1}
#Hovered:hover ~ #Target{opacity:1; }
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e7L44/1/

just beware of the browser supprot. :)

Here is some details about it :http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector